# Limit Listing of TOPN in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

I have a Dataset with two columns

```
Business Line | Availability
A             | 100%
B             | 99 %
C             | 100% 
D             | 100%
E             | 100%
F             | 100%
```

and I need to obtain the TOP 5 rows business Line by Availability, like :

```
Business Line | Availability
A             | 100%
C             | 100%
D             | 100% 
E             | 100%
B             | 99%
```

I've tried

1. Filter TOP N Pane, but since I've a lot duplicates with availability percentage, it shows me
   more than 5 rows
2. RankX DAX formula, but it gives always the same result since availibility is always the same in different business line

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your expected output does not match your data. Why is B top of the list with 100%? B has only one entry in your data table, and it is 99%. Also, if, as you say, you have a lot of duplicates in your data, why have you given an example with precisely none?

Comment: Expected output it is surely not correct, I did a mistake, obviously you have to change A with B.
Business Line | Availability
A             | 100%
C             | 100% 
D             | 100%
E             | 100%
F             | 100%
B             | 99 %

Do you know how to limit the rows of TOP N  to 5 in order to only show 5 rows with top N?

Comment: Then please eidt your post to show the correct data.